# OSM Building as Multipolygon not rendering as building

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

I have been working to improve OpenStreetMap data in my local area and I've found something that I *think* is a problem but I can't figure out how to fix it.

The basic problem is that the Jefferson County Courthouse building in Golden, Colorado doesn't render the building outline on OpenStreetMaps.org, see:  https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/39.72769/-105.20104&layers=N

When I download that bbox in JOSM however, the building outline shows up as a multipolygon named "Jefferson County Courts", with only 1 single part to the multipolygon.  I've created a note in OSM about this, see: https://www.openstreetmap.org/note/428842#map=18/39.72784/-105.20062&layers=N

---

**First question**:  Is there a **good** reason for that building to be a multipolygon?  It is one single building, so I can't think of one.

**Second question**:  Is there a way to preserve the history associated with the multipolygon, but to just make it a regular polygon?  I'd like to keep the current boundary and the history associated with it, a couple people seem to have put some good time into that shape and I don't want that to be lost.

If converting it to a singular polygon isn't appropriate, what is keeping it from rendering in the default view of OSM?  I know we're not supposed to tag for the renderer, but it's tagged as `building=public` but isn't showing up like a building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was one node to much in the outline of the building. This made the ring non-closed, preventing it from rendering.

The building is coming back slowly ...

Comment: Thank you, I never noticed that extra node.  Marked as answer because this did fix the main issue I was concerned about.

Comment: You should have got an error messsage on upload if you tried to change the object using JOSM (so did I). Not sure about other editors.

Comment: I hadn't gotten around to editing the object since I wasn't 100% sure how to approach the cleanup.  I looked through all the menus for a "remove multipolygon" option, I googled for advice and then decided to ask!  I didn't even think to make an edit to the data so JOSM would check for errors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first question: No, I cannot think of a reason the building should be mapped as two relations.

https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/5377749 is a type=multipolygon relation with the member https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/4057335 (which is a type=multipolygon relation with building and addr:-tags) which has the member https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/304424699 , which is (correctly) untagged.

Proposed course of action: get rid of the two relations, add the tags to the way. The relations don't add value to the data, they are only clutter.

Comment: Thank you, @AndreJ solved the core problem, but I will look into cleaning this up as you suggested when I have a few moments.